# Do I need to sanitise inputs when I'm using a TableAdapter to talk to a SQL Server in .NET?

Tags: .net, sql-server

I'm using a pretty simple stored procedure through a TableAdapter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/fill-datasets-by-using-tableadapters?view=vs-2017):

```
username = "Dave";
gamesDataSetTableAdapters.GetLeaderboardTableAdapter board = new gamesDataSetTableAdapters.GetLeaderboardTableAdapter();
var result = board.GetData(username);
```

My question is: Do I need to sanitise the username variable to prevent SQL injection? Or is this already accounted for in the TableAdapter stuff and I don't need to worry if someone has a username with SQL injection in it?

Comment: What do you mean by _sanitise the username variable_?

Comment: @Sami I think he means take steps to prevent sql injection.

Comment: The code given isn't helpful to understanding your question. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: Updated the question to make this clearer. Sorry, thought that was a standard term.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596057/tableadapters-sql-injection